# Doctrine with ZF2 Annotation: how to clear a multi select field?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've got a problem with my multi select fields. Here is the code:

In the Entity class

```
/**
 * @Annotation\Options({ "disable_inarray_validator":"true", "label":"Bound Checkpoints", "target_class":"Checkpoint","property":"name"})
 * @Annotation\Type("DoctrineORMModule\Form\Element\EntitySelect")
 * @Annotation\Attributes({ "multiple":"true", "class":"form-control"})
 * @Annotation\Required(false)                     
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Checkpoint", inversedBy="affectedByCheckpoints")
 */
private $boundCheckpoints;


public function __construct() {
        $this->boundCheckpoints= new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }


   public function addBoundCheckpoints( $items)
    {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $this->boundCheckpoints->add($item);
        }
    }

    public function removeBoundCheckpoints($items)
    {

        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $this->boundCheckpoints->removeElement($item);
        }
    }
```

My issue is: if I set some stuff into the field, it save it well. If I remove one, still working. But if I remove all items I set and fire the form, the removeBoundCheckpoints method is never called.

I tried to set a required validator to the form, but If I do that, I've got a validation issue.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You may find that the form element is absent from the post when submitted blank. In this case, you would need to add it back in with an empty array value.

Comment: you're right, I didn't check the post array.. as you say, the key is absent.. I added a little workaround into the template. Seems work.      
    
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding this workaround into the template.

```
{% if field.getAttribute('multiple') == 'multiple' or field.getAttribute('multiple') == 'true' %} 
      <input type="hidden" name="{{field.getName()}}" value="" /> 
{% endif %} 
{{formElement(field) }}
```